# How to update a published npm package?

Tags: npm

I recently joined a team and updated an already existing react native plugin that was published on npm. Now I want to update the package on npm.
I've tried the command
`npm publish`
but I get these errors:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/myplugin - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'myplugin@3.5.0' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

I use my browser for the link `https://registry.npmjs.org/myplugin` and it's working properly.
I have pushed the latest updated version on git so everything is OK on GitHub.
I have a npm account and I'm an admin in the organization account. Any guidance on how I can update the package on npm will be much appreciated.

Comment: This is the output of an `npm install myplugin@3.5.0` not of a `npm publish`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just logged in to my account in npm and that solved my problem.